# How to prevent Xcode 4.5 from allowing OpenGL ES2 calls

Tags: ios, opengl-es, xcode4.5

I am only including OpenGL ES1 headers, yet I am able to compile my project successfully with such lines as:

```
glReleaseShaderCompiler();
```

Is Xcode 4.5 secretly swapping out ES1 headers with ES2 headers behind the scene?  How would I be able to inspect exactly what headers are included in the build process?

Comment: It should throw a warning if multiple opengl header versions are being included - It is possible that some other framework is importing the ES 2.0 headers

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it helps to compile for armv6 or set deployment target to ios 4.

Just a suggestion, no idea if it works or not.

Comment: I don't think Xcode 4.5 supports armv6 anymore.  Ideally, I could see some verbose compiler output that shows what header files are being included, that would resolve my confusion.